# looking for a way to partition bigQuery tables by column value

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am working with genomic data. There is no outdated data so i can not partition by date and the data mass is large.

Is there a way to partition by column value? can it be automated somehow?
I would like to use it for visualization and the preferred size is 1 GB table
ay idea?

thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 2):

As of today - there is no way to partition table by column value
There is a [Partition on non-date field - feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817) for this that you can `star` to vote for it

Comment: Even if that column is a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: from what I know this feature is still not available yet. So - Yes, no way for now to partition by column value no matter what type it is